# bash script to delete folders with a name_date older than 90 days

Tags: bash

I have a folder with a large data history

```
data/
  2010.01.01/
    f1/
    f2/
    ...
  2010.01.02/
    ...
  ...
```

and I would like to have another folder with just the folders that have a name with a date in the last 90 days

```
data_recent/
  2020.02.28/
    f1/
    f2/
    ...
  ...  
  2020.05.28/
    ...
```

what is the easiest way I can sync the new folders and delete the old ones with a bash script?
The box is running on centos7

Comment: What I would do is just create soft-links to the folders with name_dates less than 90 days old in `data_recent/`. (`ln -s`). Then it's just a matter of looping over the new directories in `data/` and adding new links in `data_recent/` and looping over the links in `data_recent/` and removing links for any older than 90-days. In either case you can parse the directory name and then create a date (in seconds since epoch) with `date -d "folder_date" +%s`. You get the number of seconds for 90 days ago with `date -d "90 days ago" +%s`

Comment: the age of the data does not correspond necessarily to the date as in folder name. so could some data be re-generated later (and so the main folder would be deleted and recreated).

Comment: That's why you parse the folder name into a date instead of using `find data/ -type f -newermt "$(date -d "90 days ago" "+%F %R")"` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to convert the date folder names into Unix Epoch time so you can easily compare them.

```
#!/bin/bash

dataDir="/abs/path/to/data"
recentDir="/abs/path/to/data_recent"
daysToKeep=90
minKeepEpoch=$(date --date "$daysToKeep days ago" +%s)

# Create new links for folders that are within $daysToKeep
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' dir; do
  dirName=${dir##*/}
  dirEpoch=$(date --date ${dirName//./} +%s)
  (( dirEpoch >= minKeepEpoch )) && ln -s -t "$recentDir" "$dir"
done < <(find "$dataDir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)

# Remove links that are older than $daysToKeep    
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' link; do
  linkName=${link##*/}
  linkEpoch=$(date --date ${linkName//./} +%s)
  (( linkEpoch < minKeepEpoch )) && rm "$link"
done < <(find "$recentDir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l -print0)
```

#### Proof of Concept

Note that `./data_recent` was pre-populated with an outdated link that will be removed

```
$ tree ./data
./data
├── 2010.01.01
│   ├── f1
│   └── f2
├── 2020.02.27
│   ├── f1
│   └── f2
├── 2020.02.28
│   ├── f1
│   └── f2
├── 2020.05.27
└── 2020.05.28
    └── f1

12 directories, 0 files

$ tree ./data_recent/
./data_recent/
└── 2010.01.01 -> /abs/path/to/data/2010.01.01

1 directory, 0 files

$ ./syncFolders.sh
$ tree ./data_recent/
./data_recent/
├── 2020.05.27 -> /abs/path/to/data/2020.05.27
└── 2020.05.28 -> /abs/path/to/data/2020.05.28

2 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that great answer